# C++ component object model

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com

i want set a pointer to the dispatch for software automation with c++
my code is :

```
::CLSIDFromProgID(OLESTR("SGNSAutomation.SGNSApplication"), &clsid);
IID iid;

  HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, 
  IID_IDispatch, (LPVOID*)&pWMPDispatch);
  IDispatch * pdisp = (IDispatch *)NULL;
  DISPID dispid;
  OLECHAR * Name = OLESTR("openCase");
 HRESULT hresult =pdisp->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &Name,1,LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT,&dispid);
```

but an error occurs in last line :
Unhandled exception at 0x008B4AD7 in Win32Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

how i should solve this problem?
i think it is because i don't set pdisp pointer and i don't know how set it.
please help me
thank you

Comment: Saw that you unmarked my answer as the solution. Was there another issue?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't show the declaration of `pWMPDispatch`, but I bet it's an `IDispatch*`. It should be, because you're using `IID_IDispatch` in your `CoCreateInstance` call. So you don't need the other variable `pdisp`. Just use `pWMPDispatch`. Also, make sure you check every `HRESULT` return code. I think your code should look something like this

```
HRESULT hr = ::CLSIDFromProgID(OLESTR("SGNSAutomation.SGNSApplication"), &clsid);
if (FAILED(hr)) {
    // handle error here by returning or throwing
}

hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IDispatch, (LPVOID*) &pWMPDispatch);
if (FAILED(hr)) {
    // handle error here by returning or throwing
}

DISPID dispid;
LPOLESTR Name = OLESTR("openCase");
hr = pWMPDispatch->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &Name, 1, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &dispid);
if (FAILED(hr)) {
    // handle error here by returning or throwing
}
```

Comment: @mahdiLotfi Please don't forget to mark this as the answer.

Comment: @mahdiLotfi You upvoted but did not mark this as the answer. Please click the checkmark to the left of this answer.